# Error: Method Not Found occurring during runtime in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

This my code for a app i am trying to make but whenever i am running the code using flutter run command in vs code terminal, Error: Method not found comes for web and mobile in the main code
The main code is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'utility/colors.dart';
import 'responsive/responsive_layout_screen.dart';
import 'responsive/mobile_screen_layout.dart';
import 'responsive/webscreen_layout.dart';

void main() {
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
title: 'E-Shopping',
theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
scaffoldBackgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
),
home: const Layout(WebLayout: web(), MobileLayout: mobile()),
);
}
}
```

Here is my layout program

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../utility/dimension.dart';

class Layout extends StatelessWidget {
final Widget WebLayout;
final Widget MobileLayout;
const Layout({
Key? key,
required this.WebLayout,
required this.MobileLayout,
}) : super(key: key);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
if (constraints.maxWidth \> 600) {
return WebLayout;
} else {
return MobileLayout;
}
});
}
}
```

This is my web Screen layout code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class web extends StatelessWidget {
const web({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// ignore: prefer_const_constructors
return Scaffold(
body: const Center(child: Text("web")),
);
}
}
```

This is my mobile screen layout Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class mobile extends StatelessWidget {
const mobile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// ignore: prefer_const_constructors
return Scaffold(
body: const Center(child: Text("mobile")),
);
}
}
```

Whenever I am running the code the following error is coming

```
lib/main.dart:23:37: Error: Method not found: 'web'.
home: const Layout(WebLayout: web(), MobileLayout: mobile()),
^^^
lib/main.dart:23:58: Error: Method not found: 'mobile'.
home: const Layout(WebLayout: web(), MobileLayout: mobile()),
^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
  Script 'C:\\flutter\\packages\\flutter_tools\\gradle\\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\\flutter\\bin\\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
```

I have tried restarting vs code and the simulator but the error is still coming.

Comment: Could you format your code properly?

Comment: You trying to use page/route as a widget. Thats why it says method not found. Turn your web and mobile classes to a widget and it will be ok.

Comment: or be sure you file referances are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make your classes start with a capital
2. Import the files for each class into the file you need to use it
3. Properties are camelCase starting with lowercase

This will help improve the readability of the app and make it easier for us to  see if you're trying to call a function (which starts with lower case) or a Class constructor which starts with upper case.

Once you update that in your code and it still doesn't work leave a comment and I'll come edit my answer with your updated answer in mind.